# Rewrite all URLs to index with path as GET variable

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to forward all requests for other index.php files to the root index.php file with the path encoded as a GET variable. Here are some examples of what I mean:

> http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/index.php would become:
> http://my-site.com/?path=%2Fthis%2Fis%2Fthe%2Fpath%2Findex.php
>
> http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/ would become:
> http://my-site.com/?path=%2Fthis%2Fis%2Fthe%2Fpath%2F
>
> http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/index.php?v=var would become:
> http://my-site.com/?path=%2Fthis%2Fis%2Fthe%2Fpath%2Findex.php%3Fv%3Dvar

How can this be done with the .htaccess file?

**EDIT**
To be clear, here is what I am hoping to achieve:

- If a path is to a file called "index.php" it redirects as long is it is not the root index file. Note, said index.php file could have GET variables that should be included.
- If a path ends in a slash, in should redirect as well as long is it is not the root. Again, note said path could have GET variables that should be included.
- Otherwise, it should not redirect any other paths.

In summary, only paths to an index.php file (that are not the root) or that end in a slash should be redirected.

Comment: yes it can be done in .htaccess

Comment: @Dave How could this be achieved with the .htaccess file?

Comment: By doing some research may I suggest google as a starting point. Once you've had an attempt at it then come back with some questions when you have something to look at this is a help site not a do my work for me site.

Comment: @Dave, I have researched this but I am still having trouble. I learn best experience—seeing how things work. It would help me a great deal if someone could show me how this could be achieved. You don't have to respond if you don't feel like helping.

Answer (score 1):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! This does rewrite, however the URL bar does not change. How can I make the URL bar change to the new rewritten address. Is that possible? Sorry, I am new to URL rewriting.

Comment: Yes it is possible, make last line as: `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA,R]`

Comment: Thank you, That worked! One last question: this does not redirect/rewrite if a .php files exists at the path. For example, if I use the path:
`http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/index.php`
and that files actually exists, it does not redirect. How can this be fixed?

Comment: This redirects everything, stylesheets, js files, images. I only want to redirect the `index.php` files and paths without a specified file (such as "http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/").

Comment: But that is how it was earlier and you wrote `this does not redirect/rewrite if a .php files exists at the path` I suggest not changing nature of the problem through comments, I rolled back my last change.

Comment: I'm really sorry for any confusion. Please see my edit, it should make clearer exactly what I am hoping to achieve. I will mark your answer as accepted if it fits those specifications.

Comment: And which requirement is not being met out of those?

Comment: The first one is not being met. Currently, it only redirects/rewrites if the index.php file returns a 404 (does not exist).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. It will rewrite every URI that is not a file (like css/js/image file)

Comment: Well, I have tested it and it does not redirect paths like this:
`http://my-site.com/this/is/the/path/index.php`
It only redirects if the above path leads to a 404 (file does not exist). Why is this?

Comment: Do you understand meaning of `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` which means don't apply rule if request is for a valid file.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to URL rewriting. So is there some way I can apply this to valid files as well (following the specifications in my edit).

Comment: No if you remove `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` then it impacts css/js/images as well. It is better to keep rules this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule (.*) index.php?path=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest learning a little about [regular expressions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html#regex) in Apache's mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/index.php)$ index.php?path=$1
```

Note this will only rewrite URL's that end in index.php and leave all other URL's alone, as that's the behavior you specified. If you want to rewrite all URL's to the index:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You are correct that I would like paths called index.php to rewrite. However I would also like paths to rewrite where a file is not specified—such as my second example. How can that be done?

Comment: Then use my second example. But you might also need to either add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f before the RewriteRule, or change the RewriteRule's regex to ^(.*\.php)$ . This prevents Apache from rewriting the URL to your css, js, or image files that you might just want to leave in place. The details depend on your file structure, Apache configurations, and how your PHP is scripted.

Comment: Thanks, I am using your second example and I changed the regex. The only problem is that it infinitely redirects the root index.php file back to itself. How can I resolve this issue? Thanks for your help!